# svg rect or polygon with desired shape fill

Tags: html, svg, polygon

Trying to build below layout using svg rect and path

Below is my code as i tried,

[image]

Someone please suggest or help to do effective way either with polygon or any other ?
Facing issue with fill color, total rect is filling with color and paths are not showing

```
4 kind of layouts with fill colors (A cell with 4 partitions or 3/2/1 partition)
```

Iam very new to html and even svg, add some thoughts to build layout

Comment: Please post code as text (ideally as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) and not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it doesn't really matter if you're using  `<polygon>` or  `<path>`.
Path can be more concise, since they support relative commands or horizontal/vertical-only shortcuts ([css-tricks: The SVG `path` Syntax: An Illustrated Guide](https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/) ).

Quite likely, your stacking order needs to be reversed:
Since your `<rect>` is used as a background it has to be in the first line of your shape group.

For a better re-usability you could store your segments in a `<defs>`element like so:

```
<svg style="display:none" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 41 41" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <!-- 1/1 -->
    <rect id="seg-1-1" class="stroke rect" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" />
    <!-- 2/2 -->
    <path id="seg-1-2" class="stroke path path1" d="M0 0 L40 40 L0 40Z" />
    <path id="seg-2-2" class="stroke path path2" d="M0 0 L40 0 L40 40Z" />
  </defs>
</svg>
```

You can now use/place your elemnts via id-referenced `<use>` elements:

```
<svg  viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 41 41" >
  <use href="#seg-1-2" />
  <use href="#seg-2-2" class="green" />
</svg>
```

`viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 41 41"` is used for adjusting the svg boundaries according to the applied stroke-width. Otherwise the outer strokes would be cropped.

#### Example: multiple divisions

```css
svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:20em;
}

.svgAsset{
  display:none;
}

.stroke{
  stroke-width:1;
  stroke:#ccc;
}

use{
   fill: #eee;
}

.green{
  fill:green
}

.red{
  fill:red
}

.yellow{
  fill:yellow
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 41 41" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <!-- 1/1 -->
    <rect id="seg-1-1" class="stroke rect" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" />
    <!-- 2/2 -->
    <path id="seg-1-2" class="stroke path path1" d="M0 0 L40 40 L0 40Z" />
    <path id="seg-2-2" class="stroke path path2" d="M0 0 L40 0 L40 40Z" />
    <!-- 3/3 -->
    <path id="seg-1-3" class="stroke path path1" d="M0 0 L20 0 L20 20 L0 40 Z" />
    <path id="seg-2-3" class="stroke path path2" d="M20 0 L40 0 L40 40 L20 20 Z" />
    <path id="seg-3-3" class="stroke path path3" d="M0 40 L20 20 L40 40 Z" />
    <!-- 4/4 -->
    <path id="seg-1-4" class="stroke path path1" d="M0 0 L40 0 L20 20Z" />
    <path id="seg-2-4" class="stroke path path2" d="M40 0 L40 40 L20 20Z" />
    <path id="seg-3-4" class="stroke path path3" d="M0 40 L40 40 L20 20Z" />
    <path id="seg-4-4" class="stroke path path4" d="M0 0 L20 20 L0 40Z" />
  </defs>
</svg>


<svg  viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 41 41" >
  <use href="#seg-1-1" class="green" />
</svg>

<svg  viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 41 41" >
  <use href="#seg-1-4" />
  <use href="#seg-2-4" class="green" />
  <use href="#seg-3-4" />
  <use href="#seg-4-4" />
</svg>

<svg  viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 41 41" >
  <use href="#seg-1-2" />
  <use href="#seg-2-2" class="green" />
</svg>

<svg  viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 41 41" >
  <use href="#seg-1-3" class="yellow" />
  <use href="#seg-2-3" class="green" />
  <use href="#seg-3-3"  class="red"/>
</svg>

<svg  viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 41 41" >
  <use href="#seg-1-3" class="green" />
  <use href="#seg-2-3" class="green" />
  <use href="#seg-3-3" class="green" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below, finally achieved desired output

[image]

Below is my code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      DEMO

      <svg height="50" width="50">
        <polygon
          points="0,0 0,50 50,50 50,0"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        >
          <title>your title</title>
        </polygon>
        <text x="25" y="32" text-anchor="middle" fill="red" font-size="20">
          1
          <title>your title2222</title>
        </text>
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg height="50" width="50">
        <rect
          width="50"
          height="50"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />
      </svg>
      <svg height="50" width="50">
        <polygon
          points="0,0 0,50 50,50 50,0"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg height="50" width="50">
        <polygon
          points="0,0 0,50 50,50"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />
        <polygon
          points="0,0 50,0 50,50"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg height="50" width="50">
        <polygon
          points="25,0 0,0 0,50 25,25"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />
        <polygon
          points="25,0 50,0 50,50 25,25"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />

        <polygon
          points="0,50 50,50 25,25"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td>
      <svg height="50" width="50">
        <polygon
          points="0,0 0,50 25,25"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />
        <polygon
          points="50,0 50,50 25,25"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />

        <polygon
          points="0,50 50,50 25,25"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />

        <polygon
          points="0,0 25,25 50,0"
          style="fill: lightgray; stroke: darkgray; stroke-width: 2px"
        />
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```